# How to write K-theory Conner-Floyd Chern classes in terms of Adams operations?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, chern-classes, adams-operations

From Adams, we know that the algebra of (unstable, degree-zero) cohomology operations $K^0(BU)$ can be written as formal infinite linear combinations of canonical generators

$$\mu_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} \psi^k$$

However, from the collapse of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for BU, we also know that $K^0(BU) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[c_1^K,c_2^K,\ldots ]]$ where $c_i^K$ are the Conner-Floyd Chern classes (where I'm renormalizing them to degree zero by an appropriate power of $t\in \pi_2KU$).

Thus, it should be possible to write the Chern classes in terms of the Adams operations. How can I find these expressions?

<s>Doing the reverse is not so bad, using Hirzebruch's theory of genera: I get that $\psi^k$ is $(1+c_1^K+c_2^K+\ldots)^k$. But unfortunately I'm completing lacking in the power series wizardry that would allow me to invert this.</s>

This was wrong, since the multiplication of characteristic series of genera does not correspond to anything over on the cohomology operations side, coinciding neither with cup product nor composition (which are themselves distinct).

Comment: Why does not your last statement imply that $\psi^k$ is $(\psi_1)^k$?

Comment: it does, in the usual cup-product multiplication on $K^0(BU)$. but $K^0(BU)$ has the "extra" multiplicative structure of composition, which gives it a second, different algebra structure, and it's via this algebra structure that it acts on other K-theory rings.

Comment: actually seeing the answer now i think perhaps one wants to restrict to additive operations to make things like "algebra action" make sense.

Comment: But does not $\psi^k$ equal $(\psi_1)^k$ only on line bundles?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by that. how are you proposing to "act" by $\psi^k$ on a line bundle? the only answer i can think of is by acting on $K^0$ of the relevant space via the action of the (additive) K-theory operations algebra, and that action is via the compositional algebra structure, not via the cup-product one, like i said.

Comment: Hm maybe I am confusing things but I thought $\psi^k$ of a line bundle is its $k$th tensor power, and this then extends to other vector bundles via e. g. the splitting principle, no?

Comment: well here i'm considering this idea of $\psi^k$ not as an operator, but as an element living in a certain K-theory ring containing the K-theory operations, where the usual ring structure does not correspond to the ring structure on the additive operations (which is given by composition rather than cup product). does that make sense?

Comment: @xir As $ku(BU)\cong \mathrm{Op}(ku)$, there is an action of $ku(BU)$ on $ku(X)$ for any $X$. This is a set-map $a\colon ku(BU)\times ku(X)\rightarrow ku(X)$ satisfying among other things left-linearity and $a(f\smile g,x) = a(f,x)\smile a(g,x)$, but not e.g. right-linearity. In this sense, $\psi^k\in ku(BU)$ can act on $ku(X)$, and we generally only have $\psi^k = (\psi^1)^k$ for lines as $a((\psi^1)^k,x)=x^x$ and $\psi^k(x):=a(\psi^k,x) = x^k$ generally only for lines $x$.

Comment: hm i'm quite confused now. it seems to me that it should be true that $\psi^1([L])=[L]$ while $c_1([L])=[L]-1$.

Comment: It's possible my $c_i$'s are different from your $c_i$'s, although I don't think it's possible for $c_1$ to change virtual dimension and still have $KU(BU) = \mathbb{Z}[[c_1,\ldots]]$.

Comment: in your answer, don't you say that $c_1$ should be the pullback of $l-1$ with $l$ the tautological line bundle? i've never seen any orientation of K-theory besides $c_1(L)=L-1$ (and minor variants like 1-L, etc.)

Comment: $BU(1)\rightarrow BU$ is classifying $L-1$, so $c_1(L-1)=L-1$.

Comment: ah, that's the source of my confusion then. right, because maps into BU have to classify virtual dimension zero. so that's why my hirzebruch calculation gives the wrong result

Comment: i'm still not really convinced though, since of course the orientation $c_1(L)=L-1$ gives the same thing. and this orientation is necessary also to make the formal group law associated to tensor product of line bundles $\hat{\mathbb{G}_m}$.

Comment: why do you say that changing virtual dimension would pose a problem? the classes $c_d$ under your suggested orientation $c_d(V)=\wedge^d V$ don't converge to zero in the $I$-adic topology ($I$ the aug. ideal) which seems morally wrong to me as well.

Comment: see here for example - http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252xnotes/Lecture4.pdf - the canonical coordinate on K(BU(1)) is given by L-1, and on K(BU(n)), the conner-floyd chern classes should be elementary symmetric polynomials of these coordinates under the pullback BU(1)^n -> BU(n) classifying direct sum.

Comment: in fact your very own $\gamma$-ring formalism seems to suggest that if, say, $L$ is a line bundle, so that $\lambda_t(L) = 1+ Lt$, then $\gamma_t(L)=\gamma_t(L-1)\gamma_t(1)=\gamma_t(L-1)=1+(L-1)t$ so that $c_1(L)=L-1$. okay i'm satisfied with what's going on now

Comment: okay i see what my problem is now. of course you're right, $\gamma(-1,t)$ is not what i thought. (just replying this so any future google parvenu/es can see)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure about the facts you mention, and I don't think I'll quite answer your question, but here are some facts I do know.

First, it is not the case that all $KU$-operations can be written as (even infinite) sums of Adams operations; Adams operations are additive, and general $KU$-operations need not be. So I won't say how to write the Chern classes in terms of Adams operations, but I'll try to say something about how they relate; I apologize if I am just repeating facts you are already familiar with.

One technical remark is that $KU$-operations aren't governed by $KU(BU)$, but really by $KU(\mathbb{Z}\times BU)$. I'll talk about $ku({-}) = [{-},BU]$ instead, which is valued in nonunital rings and has operations governed by $ku(BU) = \mathbb{Z}[[c_1,c_2,\ldots]]^+$, the augmentation ideal of $KU(BU)$. From now on, all my rings will be nonunital, but you can feel free to add a unit and think of them as augmented rings instead. I think my $c_i$'s are the same as yours; they are so that if we write $ku(BU(1)) = \mathbb{Z}[[u]]^+$ with $u=l-1$ with $l$ the tautological line bundle, then pullback under summation $ ku(BU)\rightarrow ku(BU(1)^{\times n})$ sends $c_i$ to the $i$'th elementary symmetric polynomial in $u_1,\ldots,u_n$.

Adams operations can be defined in any $\lambda$-ring, and $ku({-})$ is valued in $\lambda$-rings in the usual way. So you can write $\psi^n$ as a polynomial in $\lambda^1,\ldots,\lambda^n$, but not conversely. I think the relation is
$$
t\frac{d}{dt}\log(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda^n(x) t^n) = \sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\psi^n(x)t^n,
$$
but I would not swear on the signs. Moreover, you can identify sums of Adams operations as exactly the additive operations acting on all $\lambda$-rings. Since this relates $\lambda$-operations and Adams operations, I'll just say how $\lambda$-operations relate to Chern classes.

For $\lambda$-rings like $ku({-})$ that are comprised of things like degree zero virtual bundles, it's useful to introduce the $\gamma$-operations. If I set $\lambda_t(x) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda^n(x)t^n$ for a formal variable $t$, and similarly define $\gamma_t$, then these are uniquely determined by asking first that $\gamma_t(x+y) = \gamma_t(x)\gamma_t(y)$, and second that if $\lambda_t(l)=1+lt$ then $\gamma_t(l-1)=1+(l-1)t$. You can explicitly relate these with the $\lambda$-operations via $\gamma_t = \lambda_{t/(1-t)}$, and a $\lambda$-ring structure is equivalent to a $\gamma$-ring structure.

Finally, a splitting principle argument lets you show that the class $c_n\in ku(BU)$ corresponds to the operation $\gamma^n$.

Comment: oh i never even thought of considering non-additivity but of course you're right a class in [BU, BU] doesn't have to be an H-space map for the addition. so i guess i'm really just talking about additive operations; i should go back and find if this is the case in my references as well. it's slightly confusing i guess since the additivity is a statement about having this second algebra structure under composition, a nuance i hadn't considered

Comment: ah, okay i think these $\gamma_t$ operations are the ingredient that i was not aware of. this formally looks like it corresponds to what i want. i'll think about how this relates to what i'm trying to do